# Tally Software Version Information

Tags: tally

Can Tally software's version information like Tally ERP 9 version 3.5.2 or Tally Prime version 4.1 can be retrieve by sending xml into tally?

I have tried  TallyVersion  and  Tally  nodes but received following.

Could not find TallyVersion or Could not find Tally

I am using Post method in VBA.

Comment: add the code you tried